# Replacing values in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df row like below lets call the columns as `col1, col2, col3 ad col4`-

```
 facility   20% xyzzz   facility   40% alsnan
```

I want to remove to compare the values in 2nd and 4th column. For that I want only the 20% and 40% in the column.

I am thinking if my output looks like -

```
 facility   20%  facility   40%
```

it would be easier to compare the values.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.extract`:

```
for c in ['col2', 'col4']:
    df[c] = df[c].str.extract('(\d+%)')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       col1 col2      col3 col4
0  facility  20%  facility  40%
```

Comment: Hi Chris, How do I limit this extract to a particular row? This kinda takes whole dataframe.

Comment: Its putting NaN on the columns which doesn't satisfy this condition. That is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop('column name', axis=1, inplace=True) #if you want to replace permantly the data frame
```